# Template specialization depending on type

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I try to compute a constant depending on a type and some other value with some template metaprogramming.

```
template <typename t, uint8_t number_of_bits> struct bin_size {};

template <>
struct bin_size<uint8_t, uint8_t number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 255;
};

template <>
struct bin_size<int32_t, uint8_t number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 60 * number_of_bits * 10;
};
```

However the compiler (arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors (Arduino build)) 4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322]
) complains with the following errors.

```
test.cpp:287:52: error: template argument 2 is invalid
     struct bin_size<uint8_t, uint8_t number_of_bits> {
                                                    ^
test.cpp:292:52: error: template argument 2 is invalid
     struct bin_size<int32_t, uint8_t number_of_bits> {
                                                    ^
Error compiling.
```

Without the number_of_bits feature everything works out as it should. But I can not figure out how to specialize on the typename but not on the number of bits. How can this be done?

Comment: In this specific case I resolved it like so:
    template <typename bins_t, uint8_t number_of_bits> struct bin_size {
            const bins_t upper_bound = sizeof(upper_bound) == 1 ? 255 : 60 * number_of_bits * 10;
        };
But still I wonder how this can be solved by a meta programming approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a template parameter expecting a number and use its name in your specialization :

```
template <uint8_t number_of_bits>
struct bin_size<uint8_t, number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 255;
};

template <uint8_t number_of_bits>
struct bin_size<int32_t, number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 60 * number_of_bits * 10; // You forgot "_t" here.
};
```

By doing so, the specialization is partial and still depends on something (`number_of_bits` in your case)

Here is an example : https://ideone.com/fvTa0O

Comment: Hmmm, I copied this into my code and I get exactly the same error as before.

Comment: You probably didn't copy properly. As you can see on the example, it compiles fine. At least, did you understand what I changed ?

Comment: Yes I understand what you changed. I tried this before but for unknown reasons it failed. I copied it again and now it works. I have no clue why it failed ten minutes ago.

Answer (score 3):

Make `number_of_bits` a template argument:

```
template <uint8_t number_of_bits>
struct bin_size<uint8_t, number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 255;
};

template <uint8_t number_of_bits>
struct bin_size<int32_t, number_of_bits> {
    const uint8 upper_bound = 60 * number_of_bits * 10;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The (partial) specialization should be something like:

```
template <uint8_t number_of_bits>
struct bin_size<uint8_t, number_of_bits> {
    const uint8_t upper_bound = 255;
};
```